# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar varias filas a la vez en Mysql?

Tags: mysql

Ando actualizando los datos de una columna de filas específicas (todas las filas que contengan item_name=`bc_cone`) en mi base de datos, pero son muchos datos y tardaré demasiado haciéndolo manualmente 1x1. ¿Habría una forma de crear una consulta para actualizar todo de una sola vez?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intento hacer una consulta UPDATE común con WHERE, pero no encuentro como editar todo sin dañar el resto de datos, el WHERE sería el item_name `bc_cone` porque se repite en todas filas, pero no me funciona `UPDATE items_base SET allow_stack=1 WHERE item_name='bc_cone'`

Comment: Explica si se trata de todas las filas o de alguna en específico bajo algún criterio. Muestra también lo que has intentado.

Comment: Quiero editar la columna allow_stack='1' de todas las filas que tengan el item_name='bc_cone' (como se muestra en la imagen), pero no encuentro como hacer el WHERE para no editar toda la tabla.

Comment: Exacto, tenías que usar `LIKE` para hacer coincidir parte de la cadena.

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo solucioné, solo faltó colocar LIKE a la consulta para que encuentre los parámetros o clave deseada para editar específicamente las filas que lo contenga. Quedaría así: `UPDATE items_base SET allow_stack="1" WHERE item_name LIKE "%bc_cone%"`

Answer (score 0):

Esta sentencia SQL actualiza a allow_stack=1 cuando item_name comienza con bc_cone y termina con cualquier contenido. ejemplo bc_cone*1

```
UPDATE
  item_base
SET
  allow_stack=1
WHERE item_name LIKE 'bc_cone%'
```